# How to store the previous values using variables in a loop?

Tags: java, variables, do-while

```java
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Hello {
    public static int s1;
    public static int newvalue;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        userInputAndPrimeNumber();
        calculate();
    }

    public static void userInputAndPrimeNumber() {
        newvalue = 0;
        do {
            String str1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive integer. Enter 0 to quit. ");
            s1 = Integer.parseInt(str1);

            if (s1 == 0)
                break;

            if (s1 > newvalue) {
                newvalue = s1;
            }
        } while (s1 > 0);
    }

    public static void calculate() {
        System.out.println("The greatest positive number is: " + newvalue);
    }
}
```

I would like to find the least, greatest, average, and the number of inputs the user has given (without using arrays). In the above code, I have figured out a way to store the greatest value. I'm having a hard time to figure out the remaining because I'm not able to store the previous values which the user types in. Any suggetions?

Comment: Every time they input, increment an integer

Comment: Input ONE value, BEFORE the loop and set your minimum and maximum to that value.  Also create a "sum" variable and set it the entered value as well.  Create a "counter" variable and set it to 1.  Now each time a new value is entered from within the loop, check to see if the min/max should be updated and increment the counter.  Add the value to the sum and divide by the counter to get the average.  Instead of "s1", use descriptive names like "min" and "max"...

Answer (score 0):

Made without editor so apologies in advance.
Try something like this:

```
public static void userInputAndPrimeNumber() {
       newvalue = 0;
        int lowest =0;
        int average =0;
        int count = 0;
       do {
           String str1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive integer. Enter 0 to quit. ");

           s1 = Integer.parseInt(str1);

            average = average + s1;

            if(count==0){
                lowest = s1;
            }

           if (s1 == 0){
           average = average / count;
               break;
            }


            if(s1<lowest)
            {
               lowest = s1; 
            }
           if (s1 > newvalue) {
               newvalue = s1;
           }
        count++;
       } while (s1 > 0);

   }
```

If you would add the numbers to an array at least in c# you could call max, min and avg on the array what would be more efficient.

Comment: I don't see how using arrays would be more efficient.

Comment: @AbhijeetSoni True it might not be more efficient but I'd prefer reading code like: {s1 = Integer.parseInt(str1);
            if(s1!=0){
                intArrayList.add(s1);
            }else{
                int min = intArrayList.min();
                int max = intArrayList.max();
                int avg = intArrayList.avg();
            }} Not 100% sure what it would be in java.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```java
public static void userInputAndPrimeNumber() {
    int greatest = 0;
    int lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int avgerage = 0;
    int count = 0;

    do {
        String str1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive integer. Enter 0 to quit. ");

        s1 = Integer.parseInt(str1);

        if (s1 == 0)
            break;

        if (s1 > newvalue) {
            greatest = s1;
        }

        if (s1 < lowest || lowest == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            lowest = s1;
        }

        count++;
        average = average + ((s1 - average) / count);

    } while (s1 > 0);
}
```

To see how the average logic works, visit [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/957376)

Comment: I don't think your check if it is lower will ever trigger since lowest is set to 0 and s1 will always be higher then lowest.

Comment: The lowest thing could be solved by setting the initial value of lowest as Integer.MAX_VALUE

Comment: @AbhijeetSoni You are still never hitting the check if (s1 < lowest || lowest == 0). lowest can not be 0 since it will break before the if statement. You have to initialize lowest with an instance of s1.